# Htaccess apache permalink 404 (they dont work anymore)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, nginx

we switched a website from nginx to normal apache webserver but now we have a big problem with the permalinks: all dropping 404. (before everything worked great)
I tried to configure the htaccess file correct but i am stuck on it.
Link structure where I can still access the site:
http://abc.de/subdomain/foobar/index.php?page=PageOne
Link structure how it should be:
http://abc.de/subdomain/foobar/PageOne

My current htaccess file:

```
DocumentRoot "/home/johnedoe/public_html/subdomain/"

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /foobar/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html|xml|txt|svg)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ index\.php\?page=$1 [NC,R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Of course I also activated error log for .htaccess:

```html
[root@host apache]# cat error_log
18:21:53.998 [INFO] [APVH_abc.de_Suphp56:] PID: 182662, add child process pid: 188198, procinfo: 0x2e29eb0
18:21:55.304 [INFO] [123.123.123:123:9122] File not found [abc.de/subdomain/foobar/PageOnebower_components/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2]
18:21:55.304 [INFO] [123.123.123:123:9122] File not found [abc.de/subdomain/foobar/PageOne404.shtml]
18:21:55.312 [INFO] [123.123.123:123:9089] File not found [abc.de/subdomain/foobar/PageOneassets/fonts/SairaSemiCondensed-Regular.eot]
18:21:55.312 [INFO] [123.123.123:123:9089] File not found [abc.de/subdomain/foobar/PageOne404.shtml]
18:21:55.317 [INFO] [123.123.123:123:9104] File not found [abc.de/subdomain/foobar/PageOne404.shtml]
....
18:21:55.557 [INFO] [123.123.123:123:9106] [REWRITE] strip base: '/johndoe/' from URI: '/johndoe/website/assets/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff'
18:21:55.557 [INFO] [123.123.123:123:9106] [REWRITE] Rule: Match 'website/assets/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff' with pattern '^(.*)/$', result: -1
18:21:55.581 [INFO] [123.123.123:123:9104-3#APVHjohndoe.abc.de] File not found [abc.de/subdomain/foobar/PageOneassets/fonts/SairaSemiCondensed-Regular.ttf]
18:21:55.581 [INFO] [123.123.123:123:9104-3#APVHjohndoe.abc.de] File not found [abc.de/subdomain/foobar/PageOne404.shtml]
18:21:55.594 [INFO] [123.123.123:123:9106-1#APVH_abc.de] [REWRITE] strip base: '/johndoe/' from URI: '/johndoe/website/assets/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff'
18:21:55.594 [INFO] [123.123.123:123:9106-1#APVH_abc.de] [REWRITE] Rule: Match 'website/assets/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff' with pattern '^(.*)/$', result: -1
18:21:55.892 [INFO] [123.123.123:123:9076] [REWRITE] strip base: '/johndoe/' from URI: '/johndoe/website/assets/images/favicon/favicon-32x32.png'
18:21:55.893 [INFO] [123.123.123:123:9076] [REWRITE] Rule: Match 'website/assets/images/favicon/favicon-32x32.png' with pattern '^(.*)/$', result: -1
18:21:55.926 [INFO] [123.123.123:123:9076-1#APVH_abc.de] [REWRITE] strip base: '/johndoe/' from URI: '/johndoe/website/assets/images/favicon/favicon-16x16.png'
18:21:55.926 [INFO] [123.123.123:123:9076-1#APVH_abc.de] [REWRITE] Rule: Match 'website/assets/images/favicon/favicon-16x16.png' with pattern '^(.*)/$', result: -1
...
18:22:22.913 [INFO] [123.123.123:123:9095] File not found [/home/abc.de/public_html/website/index.php]
18:22:22.913 [INFO] [123.123.123:123:9095] File not found [/home/abc.de/public_html/404.shtml]
```

Last but not least the old rewrite rule I found in nginx:

```
location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$uri&$args;
    }
```

Does anyone have an idea? Would be very important - thanks!!

Comment: Your old nginx rule does not include `page=`, try removing that from your new rules?

Comment: And include `QSA` in the flags, to append any query string, eg `[NC,R=301,L,QSA]`

Comment: Hi, already tested that on my way to the actual htaccess file but it actually doesnt help for getting  those permalinks work. At which point should I search for the correct way? Is there a possibility to 'convert' this nginx rule to htaccess (did not find working online converters..)

Comment: Your user types http://abc.de/subdomain/foobar/PageOne and you want http://abc.de/subdomain/foobar/index.php?page=PageOne right?  Your RewriteRule does not do that.  Try this: 
RewriteRule .*/foobar/(.+)$ index\.php\?page=$1 [NC,R=301,L].
You want the last part of the URI (after the last /) to be added to page=.  Right now you only accept those URL that end with / (/$).

Comment: I dont know if you exactly understand but I think you are right. Just for security I will explain it more detailed.

Comment: User goes do abc.de/subdomain/foobar. Actually the landing/home page gets shown. Oce the change from nginx to apache was done the menus permalinks did not work anymore. Menus permalink would be
http://abc.de/subdomain/foobar/PageOne
and the content is shown here 
http://abc.de/subdomain/foobar/index.php?page=PageOne
(this still works)
_________________
That acutally means I need the correct htaccess to get the permalinks work again.. Do you have any idea? Thanks!!!

Comment: Sorry I did not understand your question then.  .../foobar does show the home page.  And .../foober/PageOne going to foobar/index.php?page=PageOne still works as well?  So what does not work then?  Hopefully someone will get it :-)

Comment: Sorry, maybe I explained bad. Yes /foobar/ shows home page. On home page there are several menu points whichs links were permalinks for example /foobar/PageOne. Now those links doesnt work anymore. The only way to see the content of PageOne ist to go with /foobar/index.php?page=PageOne
--> need to do this with htaccess / mod_rewrite but I completely stucked on this... Would your rule given above work for this?

Comment: Just tested your rule on this and somehow it doesnt work here :-(

Comment: `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /foobar/index.php?$1 [NC,R=301,L,QSA]` Remove the `/` from the pattern, add `/foobar/` to the target, remove the `page=` from the target, and add `QSA`.  Also no need to escape metachars in the target.

Comment: BTW the browser will cache `301` redirects, which makes debugging very hard as your changes don't get picked up. Use `302` until they are working, they won't be cached.  Clear browser cache/history and try again.

Comment: Actually by including `R=301` you are doing an *external* redirect, which means the URL in the browser really changes.  What you really want is an *internal* redirect, so the visitor still sees `/foobar/PageOne` as the URL.  Remove the `R=301` completely to do that.

Comment: Did you crack it yet?